# How to get the word below cursor and update it in Python Gedit plugin

Tags: python, plugins, gtk, gedit

I am trying to write a Gedit 3 plugin where I want to get the word below current cursor and modify it. I tried looking at existing plugins but didn't find anything doing similar thing.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code, based on the line-tools plugin of [gedit-improving-plugins](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-improving-plugins/), gets the selected word

```
# help functions
def valid_text(start, end):
    if not start or not end:
        return False
    if start.get_line_offset() > end.get_line_offset():
        (start, end) = (end, start) # swap
    text = doc.get_text(start, end, False)
    for char in text:
        if not re.match("\w", char):
            return False
    return True
def increment(index, incr):
    newindex = index.copy()
    newindex.set_line_offset(index.get_line_offset() + incr)
    return newindex
def find_word_bound(index, step):
    condition = lambda x: not index.get_line_offset() == 0 if step < 0 else lambda x: not x.ends_line()
    while condition(index):
        newindex = increment(index, step)
        # newindex contains word?
        if not valid_text(newindex, index):
            break
        # save new index
        index = newindex
    return index
# get vars
cursor = doc.get_iter_at_mark(doc.get_insert())
start = find_word_bound(cursor, -1)
end = find_word_bound(cursor, +1)
word = doc.get_text(start, end, False)
```

After this, you can change the word by deleting it (`doc.delete(begin, end)`), setting the cursor (`doc.place_cursor(place)`) and inserting the new word at the cursor (`doc.insert_at_cursor(str)`)